# How to reinstall a tension screw of a V - brake that been fully unscrewed

Tags: maintenance

I just bought a new showgun mountain bike and I was loosening the tension screw and it came completely out and I'm having a problem putting it back in

Comment: Loosen the tension arm by clicking it out of place and then screw in the screw as normal?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah loosen the brakes ,hold them with your hands such that the brakes just does not touch the rim of the wheel then tighten it .

If you find it a bit loose the adjust the secondary screw for more accuracy .